# Update Record owner to Public Site Guest User

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, user, owner

I have a situation where some records are owned by the "Public Site Guest User" user and due to an issue another user had to create a record and fix some data.

In order for this corrected record to flow nicely into some long standing reports they need to have the owner be the "Public Site Guest User" but when I choose all options on the owner lookup dialog, I can't get that user to show up in the search at all.

Do I need to go all the way to anonymous apex code blocks to update this record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure the "Public Site Guest User" has at least read permission on the Object in question; go to the Site's Public Access Settings, edit the profile, and check Read permission for the object you're trying to assign. Without this permission, they won't be able to own the record.

Next, switch to Lightning. Interestingly, I can't seem to make the lookup field find my guest user in Classic, but it has no problem doing so in Lightning. I'm not sure how such an obvious feature is missing in Classic, but doing this in Lightning works just fine.

---

[image: Changing Ownership to Guest User]

---

If you don't want to use Lightning, you can still use the import wizard, Apex Data Loader, or other techniques to update the ownership.

You can even assign ownership by writing a Query in the Developer Console, then editing the values and using the Save button.

---

[image: Updating records in the Developer Console]

Comment: The lightning switch worked for me, so weird that you can't see that user in standard ui, Thanks!

Comment: @curtisk Yeah, I think it's odd. Glad I could help, though.